# How to update mysql 5.7 to 8.0 Amazon linux 1, ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm using MySQL 8.0.14 for my project and I want to use it for my AWS ec2 server.

I updated from 5.5 to 5.7 by following this link: [Upgrade MySQL to 5.6 on ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027744/upgrade-mysql-to-5-6-on-ec2)

But don't have any information to update to MySQL 8.0

Comment: Which OS are you using, the link is for RHEL based distributions. Is it Amazon Linx (1 or 2), CentOS or RedHat?

Comment: i'm using amazon linux 1 @ChrisWilliams

Comment: Take a look at https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-centos/. Follow the instructions as if you're running RHEL 6. Take a snapshot of your server first just incase

Comment: i got an error: `mysql-community-server-8.0.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: systemd
`

Comment: and `Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)` @ChrisWilliams

Comment: That looks like its setup using the RHEL 7 rpm rather than the RHEL 6 one. Did you run the `rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm` command

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.
https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-here-is-what-you-need-to-know/
it might help you................

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26587077)